# How to change open perspective icon?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-plugin

I need to change "Open Perspective" icon [image: Open Perspective] in my RCP application.
Is it even possible to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*This has not been tested, but I believe it should work...*

The image used for the "new perspective" item (see `PerspectiveBarNewContributionItem`) is based on the workbench images (`WorkbenchImages.getImageDescriptor(...)`).

The images of `WorkbenchImages` is installed via `WorkbenchImages.declareImage(...)` which in this case ends up as `FileLocator.find(<bundle of org.eclipse.ui>, "$nl$/icons/full/eview16/new_persp.gif", null)`.

So.. you should be able to override the existing image by installing a new fragment for `org.eclipse.ui` with your new image as the jar resource/entry named `<nl>/icons/full/eview16/new_persp.gif` where `<nl>` is your locale language - e.g. `da` for Danish and `en` for English (I cannot see you location). This image should override the default...

Answer (score 0):

You can change the open perspective icon of your RCP Application.

you just add the icon which you want to show in the icons folder in your project.

Add an extension org.eclipse.ui.perspectives and browse for your icon

and at build tab, check the icons folder checkbox

now build the plugin and run .....In open perspective you can see your application perspective having your icon.

Comment: hmmm, I think that you have tried to explain how to change perspective icon? but this was not my question, I am trying to change icon that is used for opening available perspectives (see the image in my question)